# Tumblr OAuth – Missing or invalid request token

Tags: php, api, oauth, tumblr

Having some problems with authorizing against Tumblrs API via OAuth.
This is what's going on in my **`callback.php`**:

```
require_once('../vendor/autoload.php');

// some variables that will be pretttty useful
$consumerKey = 'xxx';
$consumerSecret = 'xxx';
$client = new Tumblr\API\Client($consumerKey, $consumerSecret);
$requestHandler = $client->getRequestHandler();
$requestHandler->setBaseUrl('https://www.tumblr.com/');

// Fetch the current URL which holds important data
$link = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";

// get the verifier value
$verifier = $_GET['oauth_verifier'];

// exchange the verifier for the keys
$resp = $requestHandler->request('POST', 'oauth/access_token', array('oauth_verifier' => $verifier));
$out = $result = $resp->body;
$data = array();
parse_str($out, $data);

echo '<pre>';
var_dump($data);
echo '</pre>';

$token = $data['oauth_token'];
$secret = $data['oauth_token_secret'];
echo "\ntoken: " . $token . "\nsecret: " . $secret;

// and prove we're in the money
$client = new Tumblr\API\Client($consumerKey, $consumerSecret, $token, $secret);
$info = $client->getUserInfo();
echo "\ncongrats " . $info->user->name . "!\n";
```

Dumping out $data gives me this:

```
array(1) {
  ["Missing_or_invalid_request_token_"]=>
  string(0) ""
}
```

What am I missing? 

Not sure if it's important, but for reference for future endeavorers my initial **`connect.php`** looks like this:

```
require_once('../vendor/autoload.php');

// some variables that will be pretttty useful
$consumerKey = 'xxx';
$consumerSecret = 'xxx';
$client = new Tumblr\API\Client($consumerKey, $consumerSecret);
$requestHandler = $client->getRequestHandler();
$requestHandler->setBaseUrl('https://www.tumblr.com/');

// start the old gal up
$resp = $requestHandler->request('POST', 'oauth/request_token', array());

// get the oauth_token
$out = $result = $resp->body;
$data = array();
parse_str($out, $data);

if($data['oauth_callback_confirmed']) {
    // redirect
    $url = 'https://www.tumblr.com/oauth/authorize?oauth_token=' . $data['oauth_token'];
    header('Location: '.$url);
} else {
    echo 'Could not connect to Tumblr. Refresh the page or try again later.';
}
exit();
```

Answer (score 5):

Doh, in the end it was kind of simple, request token and secret request token is generated in **`connect.php`** and needs to be saved for access in **`callback.php`**

This is solved simply with session variables.
Since I haven't seen any working examples on how to implement this with the official Tumblr PHP clients, I hope this will be of benefit for others.

Full code below

**connect.php**

```
session_start();

require_once('../vendor/autoload.php');

// some variables that will be pretttty useful
$consumerKey = 'xxx';
$consumerSecret = 'xxx';
$client = new Tumblr\API\Client($consumerKey, $consumerSecret);
$requestHandler = $client->getRequestHandler();
$requestHandler->setBaseUrl('https://www.tumblr.com/');

// start the old gal up
$resp = $requestHandler->request('POST', 'oauth/request_token', array());

// get the oauth_token
$out = $result = $resp->body;
$data = array();
parse_str($out, $data);

$_SESSION['request_token'] = $data['oauth_token'];
$_SESSION['request_token_secret'] = $data['oauth_token_secret'];

if($data['oauth_callback_confirmed']) {
    // redirect
    $url = 'https://www.tumblr.com/oauth/authorize?oauth_token=' . $data['oauth_token'];
    header('Location: '.$url);
} else {
    echo 'Could not connect to Tumblr. Refresh the page or try again later.';
}
exit();
```

**callback.php**

```
session_start();

require_once('../vendor/autoload.php');

// some variables that will be pretttty useful
$consumerKey = 'xxx';
$consumerSecret = 'xxx';
$client = new Tumblr\API\Client($consumerKey, $consumerSecret, $_SESSION['request_token'], $_SESSION['request_token_secret']);
$requestHandler = $client->getRequestHandler();
$requestHandler->setBaseUrl('https://www.tumblr.com/');

unset($_SESSION['request_token']);
unset($_SESSION['request_token_secret']);

$link = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
$verifier = $_GET['oauth_verifier'];

$resp = $requestHandler->request('POST', 'oauth/access_token', array('oauth_verifier' => $verifier));
$out = $result = $resp->body;
$data = array();
parse_str($out, $data);

echo '<pre>';
var_dump($data);
echo '</pre>';

// and print out our new keys
$token = $data['oauth_token'];
$secret = $data['oauth_token_secret'];
echo "\ntoken: " . $token . "\nsecret: " . $secret;

// and prove we're in the money
$client = new Tumblr\API\Client($consumerKey, $consumerSecret, $token, $secret);
$info = $client->getUserInfo();
echo "\ncongrats " . $info->user->name . "!\n";
```

Comment: @mikedidthis Uhm, yes, this is using the official one? However I borrowed the idea of session vars from another lib.

Comment: My mistake, I rolled back the changes. Can you please clarify that you are mixing the official client with another? Thanks

Comment: @mikedidthis I could, but I don't see why? Using sessions is not specific to that lib, it's just how they solved getting the vars from connect to callback point. The official lib has an example of achieving what I'm doing above, but it's more of a proof of concept in my eyes. You manually need to input data to receive an access token which I don't see being useful in a real case app.

Comment: As it maybe useful for others to see the whole process? Either way, glad you sorted the issue and sorry for the error.

Comment: No problem, thanks for being super helpful with Tumblr problems :)